# Distributed Load testing using Gatling tool

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, distributed-system

Can some one please provide me the information that if open source Gatling tool support distributed load testing the way how we implement in jmeter tool master slave setup.

Regards,
Chithra

Comment: Does this answer your questioN? https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/guides/scaling_out/

Answer (score 0):

Gatling distributed load testing is featured in [Gatling Enterprise](https://gatling.io/enterprise/).